# Vim: Ctrl+S doesn't work for Russian layout (assuming I mapped the Russian key)

Tags: vim, gtk, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
map ы s "this maps the russian letter "Ы" which is on the same key
map <C-s> :w<CR>
```

Unfortunately, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> wouldn't work in Russian layout. I know this must be an old question in the vim community, but I think it previously worked for me (I must have accidentally changed the correct setting when editing the file).

I am using gvim 7.3 in Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no code for this to work in vim. If it did, it was the GUI toolkit (likely gtk) feature, not the vim one.

Comment: You might try using `<leader>s` instead. I use `<leader>w` to write.